# Windows cmd script extract version number from jar file

Tags: regex, cmd, window

I have a jar file named

```
MyApplication-1.9.1-SNAPSHOT-windows.jar
```

How do I extract the version number i.e. `1.9.1-SNAPSHOT` into a variable in windows cmd script

The `-SNAPSHOT` is optional so `MyApplication-1.9.1-windows.jar` must result in `1.9.1`

I have tried this

```
echo %JAR_FILE% | findstr /i /r "[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\(-SNAPSHOT\)?"
```

but not working

Thanks a lot

Johan

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this with pure batch.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\06\SO_53170183.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "JAR_FILE=MyApplication-1.9.1-SNAPSHOT-windows.jar"

:: Variant 1 for /f
For /f "tokens=2 delims=-" %%V in ("%JAR_FILE%") Do Set "Version=%%V"
Echo Version=%Version%

:: Variant 2 self modifying code
Set i=0&Set "Split=-%JAR_FILE%"
Set "Split=%Split:-="&Set /a i+=1&Set "Split[!i!]=%"
Set Split

:: Variant 3 shuffle
Set "Strip=%JAR_FILE:*-=%"
Set "Rest=%Strip:*-=%"
Set "Version=!Strip:-%Rest%=!"
Echo Version3=%Version%

:: wrapped powershell
For /f "usebackq" %%V in (`
  Powershell -Nop -C "[regex]::match($ENV:JAR_FILE,'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)').Groups[1].Value
`) Do set "Version4=%%V"
Echo Version4=%Version%
```

Sample output:

```
>  Q:\Test\2018\11\06\SO_53170183.cmd
Version=1.9.1
Split[1]=MyApplication
Split[2]=1.9.1
Split[3]=SNAPSHOT
Split[4]=windows.jar
Version3=1.9.1
Version4=1.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve this with `findstr`, it will not allow you to extract the matched data. I would suggest you to use PowerShell instead:

```
echo $Env:JAR_FILE | Select-String -Pattern '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,3}(-\w+){0,2}' | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```